# Avoid main process crash on plugin crash

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I was experimenting with a kind of plugin system for my other project written mainly in C and littlebit of C++.

Lets say some developer creates a plugin (lets say derived class maybe!) crashes, it can cause whole program to crash.

This is designed to be run on linux only!

**Basic requirement i am setting are as follows,**

1. plugin entry function is provided all data it needs.
2. it is not required for plugin to return any data or communicate back. but it should be allowed to do so.
3. if the plugin function causes a segmentation fault or encounters a `signal`, it *must not* affect the main program.

**for this, I am thinking of some approaches and I need more opinions and suggestions,**

1. use `fork()`, fork the process just before calling the plugin entry function and communicate with sockets or mapped memory.
2. use `threads()`, i think this will not work since thread is not seperate process and on things like segmentation faults, it will crash main thread as well.
3. use `clone()`/`clone3()`, This is very new for me. But it works similarly to fork but gives more control over cloning process.

Any other ideas or things i should consider?.

Answer (score 1):

When you add something external to your own address space and under your own user account, it has the same privileges as your application.

Therefore, any restriction you may pose within your code may be overriden by the plugin without your knowledge.

If security is top priority, then your only viable option is to host the plugin into an external process that would communicate in a secure way with the main process. If for any reason the plugin dies or causes a crash, it's only the hosting external process that is affected.

In threads, crashing the thread allows you to kill only this thread, the rest of the application may not be affected - but there might be side effects, because it's the same address space.

I'm not a unix developer (I work only in Windows) but the idea is the same there. I have an external client app that hosts the (VST audio) plugin and, if a problem occurs, I just terminate that external process.

Comment: Security and memory isolatoin wont be my top priority, all these plugins will only contain small utility functions that inform other processes stats and such..

Comment: Then a threading system would be fine I guess. It depends also who is writing your plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue not so long ago, we had a program that was supposedly stable but since it was so important to the system we needed a way to be absolutely sure it would always run.

I created a "supervisor" program that used fork() and execv() to start the new binary in a new process and waitpid() to check if it crashed, that way, if it crashed for any reason in any way possible (as long as it didn't bring the system down with it of course) the parent process would know yet still continue to work fine.

As you need communication between your two processes I'd probably recommend using a UNIX socket for the very low overhead, ease to port to network if you even wanted to and the added security over memory mapping.

Answer (score 0):

> This is designed to be run on linux only!

Just design your plugin system with inter-process communication from the start. The server listens on a socket, and plugins are separate processes that send commands to be executed to the socket and communicate via it with the server. Implement a C interface library to ease up accessing the socket, also for other programming languages to use.  That way, the server has full control of its actions and will never crush if you don't want to.

X server is the prime example of such communication. Xorg communicates with `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`.

Comment: Because i want to execute these plugin functions only if i recieve some message on mqtt topic. and i am developing this for low resource portable router. so if i had to create seperate binaries for each plugin, i think it would unnecessarily increase required space.

Each plugin may link to json-c, libmosquitto, other libuci, etc. so it would be better if i can have all plugin's code in one place.